Comparing ranks in csgo (or cs2?)
TL;DR If i am gold nova 3 in winghuman, then what's likely my MM rank? I'm looking for sites that tell me like this.

Not really updated with cs2 but for either cs2 or csgo matchmaking or csgo faceit (or cs2 faceit?), where can I find correlations between ratings/ranks in MM, faceit, danger zone or wingman/wingwoman/winghuman (it's 2024) ?
For example in chess, there are comparisons: Link1. Link2. Link3.
Case 1: In the same site but under different time controls.

Example: Between a player's blitz (about 3-5 min games) rating & rapid rating (about 8-10 min games). In lichess a rating of about 1400 rapid is about 1253 blitz:


Usually one's rating is slower time controls is higher than in faster time controls. (Of course as the supergrandmaster level, anything goes. Hikaru Nakamura for example is much better at faster than slower time controls. Wesley So is the opposite.)

In cs: I think I read something like winghuman ranks are higher than MM ranks. So I'm curious to see if there's some conversion like if 'Master Guardian 1' in winghuman is about 'Gold Nova 1' in MM.

In cs: Also, I guess there's comparing danger zone rank to winghuman or mm rank. I don't think there's danger zone yet again in cs2 though.


Case 2: In different sites but under about the same conditions.

Example: In chessc*m a rapid rating of about 1800 is about 2014 in lichess (also rapid).


This isn't quite like the previous case because the player pools are different and lichess has a higher starting rating (1500 compared to 1200). But at least it does give a sense as to what you expect your rating to be in 1 site based on your rating in another site. Eg If I'm 1800 in chessc*m after playing 500 games in 100 days, but I'm only 1800 in lichess after playing 10 games in 2 days, then obviously the interpretation is 'play a bit more than most likely you'll be at least 1900.'

In cs: I guess the analogue then is comparing faceit to MM.

Case 3: In different sites & in different conditions.
Not quite sure if this really has any big meaning but if ever...

In cs: I guess the analogue then is if ever faceit has a winghuman option. Then compare faceit winghuman to MM. Or faceit 5v5 to regular winghuman.


I am really unclear as to what are you asking. Can you put down a simple question to wrap all of what you say?

@Fredy31 if i am gold nova 3 in winghuman, then what's my MM rank? i'm looking for sites that tell me like that.

Both are different queues with different rankings. AFAIK, being 1 rank in regular MM doesnt mean you'll definitely get at least x rank in the other. Hell, coming from League of Legends theres 2 ranks, Solo/Duo queue and flex (3 or 5) queue; and even if its the exact same game behind it, people will have wildly different ranks when they are on both ladders.

@Fredy31 yet it's a thing in chess. so why can't there be a thing like this in csgo? You just plug in your rank and let people decide for themselves.
